# Permanently mute media (non-bluetooth) volume or control (with app?) media volume while connected to bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, volume

Phone: Galaxy S8

Problem: I use Bluetooth headphones all the time, I adjust volume with them or on the phone, but once I disconnect the media volume on the phone is no longer muted (or at low volume) like it was before the adjustment while using Bluetooth. It appears as if Bluetooth volume changes the non-Bluetooth media volume (but strangely doesn't seem to be the same level as the previously-connected Bluetooth; some high level)

This is a problem because sometimes I either forget to enable Bluetooth, or Bluetooth disconnects while I walk away from the phone, and I'm in a place (like work) where it's generally quiet with people around.  Then suddenly and embarrassingly it blasts my music for all to hear.  This wouldn't be a problem if the phone media volume would just stay down/muted!

I would think the possible solutions are:
1) Create some 'permanent' mute of the phone media volume
2) Some app that allows me to control Bluetooth and phone media volume independently. 
But I haven't found solutions to either.
Any ideas?

(I should note this has NOTHING to do with 'media sync' or having the blue tooth headset volume and media volume both control the same volume. I currently have this disabled.)

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: sorry no, I bet you can do it with tasker, but i ahven't bothered to try yet.  I've just been using my laptop for music now

Comment: Go to Settings > Sound > Change your "Do Not Disturb".